# How to describe coefficients and variables of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

[image]

My assumption is that, since z is decreasing over time, it would indicated:

$\frac{dz}{dt}$ is negative with units of $(\frac{m}{s})$

Gravity is positive with units of $\frac{m}{s^2}$

I am assuming the coefficients of friction are opposite of the direction of motion $\frac{m}{s}$, hence it would be negative hence both $C_l$ and $C_n$ would negative. With:

$C_l$ having units of $\frac{kg}{s}$ and $C_n$ having units of $\frac{kg}{m}$.

Are there assumptions correct? Assuming that m = kg. I believe that the units for my $C_n$ are wrong as the "sgn" is throwing me off.

Comment: Well! It depends on characteristics of the friction forces imposed on the object and the specifications of the medium... The nonlinear friction should be respect to friction of motion in liquid or gas but what about the linear one?